# Arduino Sensor API Webserver

Tags: api, arduino, webserver, esp32, arduinojson

When I load this code into my Arduino, he connects with the WiFi and shows up at my IP-Scanner. But when I open the IP of the device in FireFox nothing loads. (http://10.0.0.40/env) Is there an issue with my code, or doesnt it work like this. I have a sensor which reads the temperature and humidity. These two value should be available in my network to fetch(). With Javascript I want to display these on my local html-page. The network credentials are just censored.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN 13
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const char *ssid = "XXX";
const char *pwd = "XXX";

StaticJsonDocument<250> jsonDocument;
char buffer[250];

float temperature;
float humidity;

WebServer server(80);

void connectToWiFi() {
  Serial.print("Connect to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);

  while (WiFi.status() !=WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected. IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}



void setup_routing(){
  server.on("/temperature", getTemperature);
  server.on("/humidity", getHumidity);
  server.on("/env", getEnv);
  
  server.begin();
}

void create_json(char *tag, float value, char *unit){
  jsonDocument.clear();
  jsonDocument["type"] = tag;
  jsonDocument["value"] = value;
  jsonDocument["unit"] = unit;
  serializeJson(jsonDocument, buffer);
}

void add_json_object(char *tag, float value, char *unit){
  JsonObject obj = jsonDocument.createNestedObject();
  obj["type"] = tag;
  obj["value"] = value;
  obj["unit"]  = unit;
}

void read_sensor_data(void * parameter) {
     for (;;) {
     temperature = dht.readTemperature();
     humidity = dht.readHumidity();
     }
     delay(2000);  
}

void getTemperature(){
  create_json("temperature", temperature,"°C");
  server.send(200, "application/json", buffer);
  Serial.println(temperature);
}
void getHumidity(){
  create_json("humidty", humidity, "%");
  server.send(200, "application/json", buffer);
  Serial.println(humidity);
}
void getEnv() {
  jsonDocument.clear();
  add_json_object("temperature", temperature, "°C");
  add_json_object("humidity", humidity, "%");
  serializeJson(jsonDocument, buffer);
  server.send(200, "application/json", buffer);
}

void setup() {
dht.begin();
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
connectToWiFi();
setup_routing();

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
delay(2000);
float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
float humidty = dht.readHumidity();

}
```

Comment: By nothing loads you mean blank page or some sort of error ?

Comment: It loads and loads and loads but nothing is getting displayed (like you have an slow connection)

Comment: Have you tried debugging it at all? Adding a few `Serial.println()`'s at the right places would let you know what's being run and what's not being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loop()` code you posted looks like this:

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
delay(2000);
float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
float humidty = dht.readHumidity();

}
```

You didn't include the necessary code to allow the web server to run. The web server needs to be given a chance to run during the `loop()` or else it can't service requests.

Your `loop()` needs to include `server.handleClient()`.

You can see this [in basic examples](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/examples/HelloServer/HelloServer.ino) showing how to use the `WebServer`.

Once you add that code you'll need to rewrite `loop()` to not always delay for two seconds or else you'll be delaying the web server as well as the sensor reads.

Comment: Thank you, that solution worked. My only problem now is that my sensor values are 0.

Comment: It works now, I added float temperature = dht.readTemperature(); to the void getEnv.